# Не работает sublime text 3 с python

Tags: python-3.x, sublime-text

После запуска Любого кода, например Print('123'), консоль выводит ромбы с знаками вопроса
Буду признателен за помощь в решении проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: смените кодировку

Comment: Сменил, не помогло.

Comment: смените кодировку приложения